# Repeat different string patterns without malloc

Tags: c, string, repeat

I got a problem with my repeat method.

```
repeat("11111", 10);
repeat("22222", 10);
```

should produce output 1111111111 (10x1) and 2222222222 (10x2)
but the actual output is both 1111111111 (10x1) so my buffer is still the same.

here's my code:

```
static char buffer[PAYLOAD_SIZE];
static void repeat(char *pattern, int size) {
    int pattern_size = strlen(pattern);
    int n = size / pattern_size;   //quotient of division
    int rem = size % pattern_size; //remainder of division

    int i; char *p;
    for (i=0, p = buffer; i < n; ++i, p += pattern_size ) {
        memcpy(p, pattern, pattern_size);
    }
    memcpy(p, pattern, rem);
}
```

It's important that there's no malloc. I'm iterating over a list of patterns

```
char *patterns[5] = { /*5 different patterns*/ }
```

and they might be all of different length.

Greetings,
Jan

Comment: Hmmm, I cannot reproduce your problem. I define five patterns, run `repeat` on them and print out `buffer`. The code is okay, unless there is something wrong in the calling code. (You don't null-terminate the repeated string in `buffer`, but I don't know whether that is by design or not.)

Comment: yes that's intended. But if it works for you then I guess I have to take a deeper look into the other code. Thanks for verification.

Comment: Suggest using non-repetitive patterns to help debug like "12345".  Show `patterns` and how it is used.

Comment: `buffer[PAYLOAD_SIZE];`  need memory management.,

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for others so this question can be closed I think... have to figure out what the problem is...